# I want to write a MapReduce Program to print the last word of every String of the given code

Tags: mapreduce

Data:
1979   23   23   2   43   24   25   26   26   26   26   25   26  25
1980   26   27   28  28   28   30   31   31   31   30   30   30  29
1981   31   32   32  32   33   34   35   36   36   34   34   34  34

Mapper:

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
               String line = value.toString(); 
         String lasttoken = null; 
         StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line,"\t"); 
         String year = s.nextToken(); 

         while(s.hasMoreTokens())
            {
               lasttoken=s.nextToken();
            } 

         int val = Integer.parseInt(lasttoken); 
         context.write(new Text(year), new IntWritable(val)); 

      }
    }
```

Reducer:

```
 public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer< Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable >
```

{

```
  //Reduce function 
  public void reduce( Text key, Iterator <IntWritable> values, 
     OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
     { 
       int val=0; 

        while (values.hasNext()) 
        { 
           val=values.next().get(); 
           { 
              output.collect(key, new IntWritable(val)); 
           } 
        }
```

I'm getting a numberFormatException.

Comment: I tried using the statement    int val=Integer.parseInt(lasttoken.trim()); Now it's giving a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception is probably here:

```
int val = Integer.parseInt(lasttoken);
```

Print the value before that statement and see what it is. It may be empty, null, or just not a number.
A good thing to try is to call `trim()` on the lasttoken. This removes leading and trailing whitespaces. It may be that is has some extra spaces or newlines.

Either way, you should check that `lasttoken` is not null (may happen if `s` is empty), trim it and check that is is a number either with some utility method or by catching the NumberFormatException. Handle that in a meaningful way to prevent your program from crashing.

Comment: It worked. I had to remove the "/t" in StringTokenizer though.